# NSMutableDictionary losing data?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
sprite.extraData
```

Is a NSMutaleDictionary.

In one method, I do this:

```
[sprite.extraData setObject:@"HELLO" forKey:@"NAME"];
```

Now, in a different method, I do this:

```
    for (CCSprite *anim in animations) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[anim.extraData objectForKey:@"NAME"]);
    }
```

Where *sprite* is a child of the NSMutableArray *animations*.

When I try to print the name, I get *(null)*. Why is that?

Comment: Most likely, check if your extraData is even initialized. NSLog it and see..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you initialize the extraData of sprite?

Make sure you do something in the CCSprite init file like:

```
extradata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thank you. Noob mistakes :(. This is weird, because I was almost sure that there was other data that I was actually able to access before from that dictionary..